# Win10 Storage Spaces - Missing capacity?

Tags: windows-10, raid-5, storage-spaces

I'm confused.

I have a "parity" Storage Space consisting of 4 x 3 TB drives in my Win10 file server (I think "parity" is roughly equivalent to RAID5).

This should give me roughly 9 TB of usable space, but I've only got 5.5 TB.

How do I get access to the rest? See attached screenshot.

[image]

I discovered that if I put 8.25 in the "Storage space size (maximum)" box (middle window of screenshot), then my available space on drive E: ("Raid5") increases proportionately.

But it seems Win10 will let me put in a number that represents more than n-1 drives worth of space - doesn't that kill the parity protection?

*The reason I'm running Storage Spaces is to get protection against HDD failure - I don't want to do anything that breaks that.*

It seems to even allow a number larger than the total of all 4 drives space - at what point do I lose protection against a drive failure?

I've looked online for documentation but everything I've found is about Windows 8 and/or Server - nothing that addresses these questions about Win10.